# Visual Studio 2010 sort functions in the editor alphabetically

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

does anyone know a way to sort the functions of a class in the editor (c#) alphabetically?
i.e.

```
public class Foo
{
    public void B() {...}  
    public void D() {...}
    public void A() {...}
}
```

After sorting the class should look like

```
public class Foo
{
    public void A() {...}
    public void B() {...}  
    public void D() {...}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sort my code (by method name) in Visual Studio 2008?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159862/how-do-i-sort-my-code-by-method-name-in-visual-studio-2008)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MZ-Tools addin](http://www.mztools.com/v6/features.aspx#SortCodeElements) can do this.

Answer (score 3):

Create this macro.

Select the text to sort, and run the macro.

```
Sub SortSelectedText()
    Dim Selection As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
    Dim Lines() As String = Selection.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, Chr(13)).Split(Chr(13))
    Array.Sort(Lines)
    DTE.UndoContext.Open("Sort Lines")
    Selection.Delete()
    Selection.Insert(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Lines))
    DTE.UndoContext.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: It's not about plain sorting the text in the class of course. I thought it would be clear that the "..." indicate there can be something in the function body as well... which of course should not be sorted the whole functions should be moved around and end up sorted.

Comment: Lol, yep.  I interpreted it as the function was all on one line.

Comment: +1 anyway, because that macro is just was I was looking for ;-)

Comment: Humm.  If you could write one to turn the function into one huge friggen line of text, and one to undo that, then the above macro would work :)

Answer (score 2):

You can check the Open Source project NArrange, it can sort the using statements as well as all the members and classes in your files, and much more.

http://www.narrange.net/

The latest version is from 2009-12-05, so the project may not evolve any more, but it looks stable enough already.

Comment: going to give this a shot, thanks! I know Eclipse can do this for .java files and was hoping for the same functionality. Didn't realize how much I appreciated this functionality until my c# classes started breaking 1500 lines of code :D

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [codemaid](http://www.codemaid.net/)? Is open source.
There are others like ReSharper that are really good too.