# Sort functions in module in alphabetical order

Tags: visual-studio, f#, refactoring

Is there an easy way to sort functions in modules in alphabetical order in VS 2010 ?
My question is the same as this one, but for F# :
[How do I sort my code (by method name) in Visual Studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159862/how-do-i-sort-my-code-by-method-name-in-visual-studio-2008)

Comment: Are you asking how to modify your code this way? (I think that would be a terrible idea.) Or just how to get an alphabetical list of functions?

Comment: In my module there are a lot of independent short functions that are just functional wrappers around a big OO API. But I understand that such an attampt is not a good Idea in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable an extension that adds [support for navigation bar in F# editor](http://tomasp.net/blog/regions-navigation.aspx) in Visual Studio. This shows a list of functions which are in the current file and the list appears to be sorted in alphabetical order.

[image: Navigation bar in F#]

As Jack says, there is no easy way to sort the functions by hand (and it would not make much sense), but if you want to sort them so that you can easily navigate through the file, then a navigation bar should help.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't an easy way to do this, and it doesn't make sense to do so in F# -- unlike C#, the order in which you declare your functions and values matters (a great deal!) in F#.